# List component of material-UI is not working. None of the list code shows up while inspecting element

Tags: material-ui

```
<Grid item>
    <Paper square>
        <List aria-label="contacts">
            <ListItem button>
                <ListItemText primary="Chelsea Otakan" />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button>
                <ListItemText inset primary="Eric Hoffman" />
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Paper>
</Grid>
```

Used this code from material-UI documentation, but nothing shows up.

[Image of Paper with an icon only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu4HY.png)

On inspecting element only  with  tag shows up

```
    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="contacts">
<path d="M3 13h2v-2H3v2zm0 4h2v-2H3v2zm0-8h2V7H3v2zm4 4h14v-2H7v2zm0 4h14v-2H7v2zM7 7v2h14V7H7z"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto import from VSCode imported List from material-ui/icon.
Issue solved after importing List from material-ui/core.